# Excel Filtered Cell Copy

Tags: excel, copy, cell, filtered

Is there anyone here that knows how i can get the value of a filtered cell to display in another cell? Like for example, i have in column G Row 12 a value A and the it goes down until E so Column G Row 12 = A Row 13 = B Row 14 = C and so on. I created a macro that if i click on it, all the info for A will appear in Row 12.

Now i have a cell C 20 that i need to display the information of Cell G 12 after i have filtered using my macro button A, B, C and so on.

Cant find any answer